# Matploitlib image displaying at place of button

Tags: image, matplotlib, button, tkinter

I have troubles using Matploitlib. My aim is to create program, which will be displaying image, with buttons allowing it's edition.

I started from the button allowing to pick an image, and I already have meet a problem. I wish image to load at the center of the window, but it loads at the place of button.

How to create a figure with fixed position, and how to choice it to display the image?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import tkinter.filedialog as dialog

class Index(object):

    def load(self, event):
        filename = dialog.askopenfilename()
        img = plt.imread(filename)
        plt.imshow(img)

callback = Index()
axload = plt.axes([0.59, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])

bload = Button(axload, 'Load')
bload.on_clicked(callback.load)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found an answer by myself.

To create new axis

```
ax=plt.subplot(111)
```

and then, to use it instead of existing one, simply

```
ax.imshow(img)
```

instead of

```
plt.imshow(img)
```